# VScode pyenv not integrated

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I created a pyenv and have encountered the issue of the terminal says that

> pyenv: shell integration not enabled.

I am running this in on Mac OS

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like after installing pyenv, you still need to follow [the steps to configure your shell's environment for Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout).

The steps are specific to your shell (e.g. bash, zsh) and how you installed pyenv (e.g. Homebrew, Git checkout)

In my case, I installed pyenv with Homebrew and I use zsh, so I must add this line to my `.zshrc`:

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

Are you using a specific terminal, such as the build-in macOS terminal? You should [make sure that your terminal app is configured to run a login shell](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/MacOS-login-shell)

Finally, if you are running your code from inside an IDE, you should check how your IDE handles python environments. For instance, Visual Studio Code's Python Extension [automatically looks for interpreters installed by pyenv](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments).

Hope this is helpful. I started with python programming last year and was happy to find pyenv as it helps maintain an isolated python environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, my problem occurs only inside VSCode.
Just updated the pyenv environment var to the desired version:

> PYENV_VERSION=3.7

You may add this line to the end of `~/.zshrc` or any other shell you might be using. If you are unsure of which shell it is, run `echo $$`