# VSCode task with pyenv and zsh

Tags: python, zsh, pyenv, zshrc, pyenv-virtualenv

I'm having an issue with configuring tasks for VSCode while using pyenv-virtualenv (not virtual env!), kind of similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71594920/vscode-pyenv-not-integrated) but it is not solved and it also refers only to .zshrc not .zprofile.

I have a a pyenv environment configured and that python interpreter is selected in the project. In terminals inside VSCode I can execute code and the terminal automatically has loaded the correct pyenv.

However, when running VSCode tasks the task fails to activate the pyenv virtualenv of the project.

E.g. in the terminal of my project I get:

```
(proj) % pyenv local
projenv
(proj) % python --version
Python 3.10.4
```

I've tried .vscode/tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Run some python",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "pyenv activate projenv && python --version",´
        }
}
```

Outputs:

> Python 2.7.18

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Run some python",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "pyenv activate projenv && python --version",´
        }
}
```

Outputs on task run:

> Failed to activate virtualenv.
>
> Perhaps pyenv-virtualenv has not been loaded into your shell properly.
> Please restart current shell and try again.

In my ~/.zprofile I have:

```
echo "Hello .zprofile"
```

And in my ~/.zshrc I have:

```
echo "Hello .zshrc"
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

When running the tasks I get the "Hello .zprofile" but not the output from "Hello .zshrc" where the pyenv activation is. When I manually create a new VSCode terminal it outputs both.

Now if I duplicate or move the pyenv activation into .zprofile the pyenv virtual env activates and the task runs.

But why does VSCode not read both my .zprofile and .zshrc files to begin with?

Comment: The profile and rc files are used by the shell (bash, zsh etc.). VSCode has no knowledge of them. I have not tried this in this way but I have used the ordinary venv system. I suggest you add a script to start the venv and run your commands. Then in the `tasks.json` just add a command to run that script.

Comment: @OldBoy pyenv works by hooking into your terminal and routing binary commands to the specific pyenvs; which is why running "a script" does not work to trigger them, but the terminal needs to integrate it. What I find odd is how the `profile` file gets loaded but not the `rc` file.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how it works. It cannot "hook into" a terminal. All it does is set some environment variables and PATH values so that the selected version of Python and its associated libraries are invoked.

Comment: I just checked the documentation for `zsh` and came across this statement explaining `.zshrc`: **This sets the environment for interactive shells**. And since the shell invoked by VSCode to run your project is not an interactive one, your .zshrc file does not get invoked.

Answer (score 0):

To activate `pyenv-virtualenv` with zsh place the `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` inside the `.zprofile` and not `.zshrc`. The former gets executed when VSCode creates a terminal, the later does not.